# read_csv with regex

Tags: python, pandas

**csv data example:**

```
<pre>2019-08-15 00:00:06,430 0:0 - {"info":{"name":"LTD - PUBLIC"}}</pre>
<pre>pd.read_csv(filepath, sep= ' - ', header=None, engine='python')</pre>
```

**expected:**

```
<pre>
date                           info
2019-08-15 00:00:06,430 0:0    {"info":{"name":"LTD - PUBLIC"}}
</pre>
```

**error message:**

> ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 1, saw 3. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: It isn't related to a multi-char delimiter. You will need to change the quote delimiter also. The issue is that this really isn't a CSV file format. The way a CSV file works is that if a field contains the field delimiter, the entire field is surrounded by quote delimiters, which isn't the case here.

Comment: The parser behaves as expected, because the separator ` - ` indeed occurs twice. It is required that your separator does **not** appear within a cell of your table. Imho you should change your input format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `regex` sep

```
temp = StringIO("""  
2019-08-15 00:00:06,430 0:0 - {"info":{"name":"LTD - PUBLIC"}}
""")


df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep=r' - (?={)', engine='python',header=None)
df.rename({0:'date',1:'info'},axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                          date                              info
0  2019-08-15 00:00:06,430 0:0  {"info":{"name":"LTD - PUBLIC"}}
```

Comment: Thanks iamklaus. your solution helps me a lot!